# What are the IOTA disk space needs?

Tags: tangle, requirements

This is along the lines of "[What are the minimal system requirements to run a full node (iri)?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-are-the-minimal-system-requirements-to-run-a-full-node-iri)", but I'm *specifically* asking about disk space.

The current Bitcoin blockchain data is around 170 GB in size. The Ethereum state data is around 110 GB (though varies depending on which client you're using, and which download/pruning mode).

The answers to the below questions are perhaps moving targets, but it'd be good to get a ball park idea.

- What is the current size of the IOTA chain data (the tangle)?
- What is the expected rate of growth, given current rates of adoption?
- Are there any pruning or compression options I can use to reduce my disk footprint?

If I'm going to require a couple of 1TB drives in a few months, then it'd be useful to know about it now, rather than having to upgrade later.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the current size of the IOTA chain data?

Right now the whole IRI directory on my Ubuntu server is 5.2gb. The current database is 4.9gb and is likely due for a pruning (snapshot in IOTA terms).

> What is the expected rate of growth, given current rates of adoption?

Very difficult to answer this question given how early it is in the IOTA development cycle but with a good snapshot plan, disk space will probably not become a factor.

> Are there any pruning or compression options I can use to reduce my disk footprint?

Snapshots are currently conducted to prune the tangle which keeps the disk requirements to a minimum.

Right now memory and CPU are much more important than disk capacity. SSD is recommended due to the heavy IO.

Answer (score 6):

I did a crude test based on the Tangle data available here http://store.alon-e.com/IOTA_DBs and then fitted a projection function to it.

So the **whole size of the Tangle** (counted from December 2016) *could* easily go up to 100 GB by mid 2018.

[image]

Comment: In the future majority of the nodes will be using Swarm Intelligence. They won't need much disk space. I'm running a prototype of such a node right now and don't even bother with storing the transactions.