# Can I run a full node on Galaxy S8?

Tags: node

Are any android nodes in production for use on mobile devices? Running a full node on android is my goal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the minimal system requirements to run a full node (iri)?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-are-the-minimal-system-requirements-to-run-a-full-node-iri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. The only implementation of the protocol so far is [IRI](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri) and it needs java and quite a bit of RAM to run. You can't even run it reliably on a Raspberry Pi atm. It would also drain your battery to the ground on no time and require constant connectivity with the network.

Comment: New light-weight **iri** that can be run on Raspberry Pi would help tangle network a lot.

Comment: IRI is not the issue itself. It's the Database. They using rocketDB. And you cannot compile RocketDB on ARM. There are some ARM ports but they ware still on version 1.1 or similar.

Comment: @PhilippBlum RocksDB (Rocks not Rocket)

Comment: @mihi Same same but different. Thanks for correcting me ;)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I do not believe you can currently, software wise.

Second of all, this would be a bad idea. Why? You need to ensure that your node is synced and online as much as possible in order to be an ideal neighbor. Your phone will be bottlenecked by data, unless you have an unlimited data plan, as well as times where it runs out of battery and dies, which will hurt your reputation as a node.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, running a full node on android is not currently possible.

Comment: Do we see a project in pipeline?